# Python pickle method __getnewargs__ not working

Tags: python, pickle

The idea is to extend `datetime` class, so I can create object with simple `Day('20150208')`

```
from datetime import datetime
from pickle import dumps, loads

class Day(datetime):

    def __new__(cls, date):
        day = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
        return super().__new__(cls, day.year, day.month, day.day)

    def __str__(self):
        return datetime.strftime(self, '%Y%m%d')

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        print('__getnewargs__ called')
        return (self.__str__(), ) 

day = Day('20200506')
print(day)
```

The problem is that this object can't be properly serialized:

```
print(loads(dumps(day)))
```

gives:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str not bytes
```

It's also interesting that `print` statement inside of `__getnewargs__` is not called, so it seems that `__getnewargs__` itsef is not called.

**How to resolve this?**

I tried with `__reduce__` too, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` implements `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__`. This supersedes `__getnewsarg__`. You have to overwrite `__reduce_ex__`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pickle import dumps, loads

class Day(datetime):

    def __new__(cls, date):
        day = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
        return super().__new__(cls, day.year, day.month, day.day)

    def __str__(self):
        return datetime.strftime(self, '%Y%m%d')

    def __reduce_ex__(self, prot):
        return (self.__class__, (self.__str__(),))
        

day = Day('20200506')
print(day)

print(loads(dumps(day)))
```